# Incorrect review options

Tags: support

The review queue currently shows me https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/8959 in the late answers section. The options given for review are *I'm Done*  and *Skip*. *No Action Needed* is grayed out and not available. although. I didn't edit or vote on this answer and therefore expected that *No Action Needed* is available and *I'm Done* is invalidated.

Comment: Have you commented to it?

Comment: @ProgramFOX No, neither the answer nor the answer.

Comment: @Howard you did add a flag to that answer though

Comment: @m0sa Not that I am aware of - what kind of flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already added a flag to this answer:

[image: flag info]